# Parallel loop in R, Do I need rcpp?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

I am using foreach to sample from a complicated function in R. Since this is an independent sampling, this is highly parameterizable. However, as long as I increases the sampling size my routine is not possible to do it on a descent time in a normal computer anymore.

So, I would like to ask for advises to speed up this process. A minimal example would be like this

```
devtools::install_github("franciscorichter/dmea02")
library(dmea02)

test <- function(n){
  no_cores <- detectCores()- 1
  cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
  registerDoParallel(cl)
  tree = sim.tree(seed=1)$tree.extant
  trees <- foreach(i = 1:n, combine = list) %dopar% dmea02::rec.tree(tree=tree, pars=c(0.8,0.1,40))
  stopCluster(cl)
}


system.time(test(10))
system.time(test(100))
system.time(test(1000))
```

and as I said as long as I increases the sampling size to higher orders then it start taking too much time.

I know that writing the loop on C++ and using Rcpp could eventually help, but I am not a computer scientist and I do not know how to code in C++ so it would take me some time to learn it, and I am not completely sure if it would really improve a lot.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest some profiling to assess where the bottleneck is. My guess is that it's in the *sampling* step, `rec.tree`, in which case coding your *sampler* in C++ *could* help, though you may be able to optimize the sampler in pure R.

Comment: Yeap, the problem is clearly with `rec.tree`.